# Sort expandable listview

Tags: android, sorting, java-me, expandablelistview

I want to sort an expendable listview dynamically. Could someone tell me how to accomplish this?

I've tried sorting the group name but then the child elements don't get sorted.

Comment: how did you got the Group sorted? It is not just an ArrayList<?>

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Basically what I did was sort it using custom comparator methods.

Answer (score 0):

I think we would need more details about the code, without the code it's hard to tell but anyway here is a link to some code maybe it will help you:
https://github.com/commonsguy/cwac-touchlist